# Android Studio, keystore lost with update

Tags: android, android-studio

I used to have Android Studio 0.6.x and it managed my keystore for my app. I did not create a backup file or so (which was stupid afterwards).

Then I installed Android Studio 0.8.x over 0.6.x and now Android Studio does not find they keystore file anymore :(
A File Recovery Programm couldn't find it as deleted or so either. Is there any chance to find that file or is it just lost? :(

Comment: Android Studio given choose location for your keystore so have you not remember this path ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio can not maintain any backup when you update new one. so in your case your file permanent lost you can not get back using any software.

Answer (score 0):

There is something u can try, search for  " *.jks " in your entire drive. android studio must have stored it somewhere.

Android studio update probably shouldn't delete a keystore file.I recently updated from 0.6.x to 0.8.x and the keystore file was still there in the same directory. If the file is stored in some directory which u cant find, it is not detected by file recovery software as it has not yet been deleted.

I hope you find it.